# Scroll Up in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve scroll up and scroll down using recycler view. Scroll down if fine, but i don't know how to do scroll up?

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        Log.e(TAG,"Onscrolled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        Log.e(TAG,"State"+newState);
        if (newState==2) {
            //do scroll down
        }                           
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about pragmatic scroll or user initiated scroll ?

Comment: @LostPuppy user initated Scroll

Comment: wait I don't understand your problem, user initiated scroll is already handled by the LayoutManager are you trying to do something different in those methods other than what you have posted ?